# oracle SQL to Copy value to leading rows using update

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, propagation

Iam having a table with millions of records. I have some records which needs to be copied to next row values. 
EG: Table A is having followingcolumns (A,B,C,D,E,F)
If the source values is like

```
A   B   C   D   E   F
1   1-Jan   1   abcd    1-Jan   abcde
2   1-Feb   0   abcd    1-Feb   def
3                               ghi
4                               jkl
5                               mno
6                               pqr
7                               stu
8                               xyz
9                               defg
```

I have to copy paste those values to leading rows in the following way.
Here iam trying to update next row if even with same values as row 1, if its odd with row2.

```
A   B       C     D      E
1   1-Jan   1   abcd    1-Jan
2   1-Feb   0   abcd    1-Feb
3   1-Jan   1   abcd    1-Jan
4   1-Feb   0   abcd    1-Feb
5   1-Jan   1   abcd    1-Jan
6   1-Feb   0   abcd    1-Feb
7   1-Jan   1   abcd    1-Jan
8   1-Feb   0   abcd    1-Feb
9   1-Jan   1   abcd    1-Jan
```

Thing is iam using a simple update command to perform this. This is taking very long time as the actual table has more than 10 million records and the operation is performed on 10 columns.

Is there any way I can propagate values to next row much faster?

Comment: thanks Mat i was about to update the table format

Comment: Can you show your update query or explain better what is the pattern to update data? You said you're updating odd rows with the value but how are they sorted?

Comment: p.s. this is a terrible design.  i would never trust the resulting information was correct -even if you get this update to happen the way you want.

Comment: I was just giving sample data set, this is not a simple odd even propagation , in actual issue i am to update table based on set of criteria like col B1 will have to be copied to B2 based on C1 vaules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should do the trick as long as A contains adjacent values.
If this is not the case, than use `row_number() over (order by A)` as a first step and change the query accordingly.

Theoretically NTH_VALUE should have been a better fit, but I suspect it has a bug.

```
select    A
         ,lag (B,floor((A-1)/2)*2) over (order by A)  as B
         ,lag (C,floor((A-1)/2)*2) over (order by A)  as C
         ,lag (D,floor((A-1)/2)*2) over (order by A)  as D
         ,lag (E,floor((A-1)/2)*2) over (order by A)  as E

from      t
;
```

The generic case for N rows would be

```
select    A
         ,lag (B,floor((A-1)/N)*N) over (order by A)  as B
         ,lag (C,floor((A-1)/N)*N) over (order by A)  as C
         ,lag (D,floor((A-1)/N)*N) over (order by A)  as D
         ,lag (E,floor((A-1)/N)*N) over (order by A)  as E

from      t
;
```

Comment: lag is the right direction.. it is unclear if the sample data of 2 records with values is what he has in real life - so this might need to be modified..

Comment: @waiting,does that answers your needs?

Comment: @waiting, glad to hear. Since it answers the question, please mark this as a correct answer